# Why output of LEN() is different of DATALENGTH()

Tags: sql-server

I used the LEN() function in all parts of my program code, and I found that the return value was wrong. So I used the DATALENGTH() function and saw that it returns the correct value. My problem was solved, but I'm wondering why these two functions function are different!?

```
PRINT LEN(' ') -- answer is 0
PRINT DATALENGTH(' ') -- answer is 1
```

Comment: LEN measures the number of characters of a literal, while DATALENGTH  measures the number of bytes to store the value

Comment: Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Be advised that datalength returns _number of bytes_. `SELECT DATALENGTH(N'a')` returns 2!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation explains this one.

[LEN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks.**

*Emphasis mine*

[DATALENGTH (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> This function returns the number of bytes used to represent any expression.

As you have a value with a single (trailing) space, it's length is 0, however, the space is still stored; and with a `varchar` each character is 1 byte in size.

Answer (score 1):

**`LEN` function** Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks, therefore, it is returning 0.

While `DATALENGTH` including the trailing blank.

If you will pass two blank spaces while calculating length. The `LEN` function still will return 0 while the `DATALENGTH` function will return 2.

Comment: If you will pass two spaces, It will return 2, if you will pass three spaces return 3 as it will count the spaces as well but LEN does not count it.

Comment: Misread, your post, I thought you were specifically referencing the OP's example.

Comment: Ok, no problem, yes as per the given example above by Zolfaghari. It would return 1.

Answer (score 1):

LEN is use to return character length, in case of blank it is counting it as 0.
You can say LEN will trim the string for calculation.

DATALENGTH is use to count memory space (bytes).

Find this link https://database.guide/len-vs-datalength-in-sql-server/